# How to use iOS speech API offline

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I have an objective-C app currently using the iOS speech-to-text and text-to-speech APIs.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech

Both are working, however they both only work when there is an Internet connection, they do not work offline.

How can I enable the APIs to work offline?

Comment: The post answers first say it is not possible, they say it is possible on some devices. So the question is which devices? and what code needs to be different from the online speech code? I have a client that has a device where offline dictation works, but our speech API usage does not?

Comment: and for the devices that support it, how do you enable it?

Comment: @James : I have similar requirements. Can you please give some reference of your solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this does not appear to be possible.